# How can I control my logo size in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.new-application-menu {
  background-color: #47484c;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 2px #000000;
}

.new-application-menu ul {
  color: #fff;
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
}

.new-application-menu ul li {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 0.01px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background-color: #27A9E3;
}

.new-application-menu ul li p {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.new-application-menu ul li i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1 new-application-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
    <li><img src="assets/Img/logo2.png" width="55" height="95"></li>
    <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">description</i>
      <p>بانک جامع اطلاعاتی</p>
    </li>
    <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">assessment</i>
      <p>نبض شهر</p>
    </li>

    <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">colorize</i>
      <p>آزمایشگاه شهری</p>
    </li>
    <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">remove_red_eye</i>
      <p>رصد طرح های توسعه ی شهری</p>
    </li>
    <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">location_city</i>
      <p>رصد پروژه های شهری</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I'm using this code and my list feature's height exceeds my page size, it automatically adds a scrollbar to my page and it causes to my grid system to overlay each other. How can I prevent this overlay?

Comment: Be a little more clear what's wrong, and what it is you can't seem to get to work properly.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kX2PX5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your custom class like `.myLogo` as i added

```css
.new-application-menu {
    background-color: #47484c;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 2px #000000;
    
}
.new-application-menu ul
{
    color: #fff;
   /* border: 1px solid white; */
}
.new-application-menu ul li
{
        padding: 8px;
        border-bottom: 0.01px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        background-color: #27A9E3;

  
}
.new-application-menu ul li p
{
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 5px;
        
        
  
}

.new-application-menu ul li i
{
        font-size: 12px;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        
  
}

.myLogo{ width:100px; height:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1 new-application-menu">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                     <li><img src="assets/Img/logo2.png" width="55" height="95" class="myLogo"></li>
                     <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">description</i><p>بانک جامع اطلاعاتی</p></li>
                     <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">assessment</i>  <p>نبض شهر</p></li>
                     
                      <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">colorize</i><p>آزمایشگاه شهری</p> </li>
                      <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">remove_red_eye</i><p>رصد طرح های توسعه ی شهری</p> </li>
                      <li> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">location_city</i><p>رصد پروژه های شهری</p> </li>
                  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: see this link please

Comment: What you want? i'm not able to understand please clarify